# Using JSON without Core Data

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4.5

Can I use this technique, or will it get my app rejected by Apple?

- The application starts, downloads some JSON data, and stores it in an array.
- A `UITableView` loads the data from the array.
- When the user starts the application again, the application again downloads the JSON data and stores it in the array, and the `UITableView` again loads the data from the array.

Is this OK, or I should use Core Data to store the data?

Note that some data may change in the JSON, so if I store it using Core Data, it will be difficult for me to track changes and reflect them in Core Data.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen rejections for excessive data use, so that would depend on your data.

Comment: What UX would you expect if the network was unavailable?

Comment: The JSON holds University class data and its some time change e.g.  (class room number).

Comment: I agree with @PassKit, that the real issue is not whether Apple will reject or not. The question is what the graceful user experience would be. What do you want the app to do if there is a failure in the Internet connection?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you,I understood your idea, but the second answer gave me the technique I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PassKit is right, that you should think about what you want the app to do if there's no Internet connection. Do you want the app to crash or just show nothing at all? Probably better, show the user the last known information, perhaps showing them the date and time that it was last refreshed and/or warn them that it might not be current.

To do that, you will want to save the JSON after it's successfully downloaded. You don't need to use Core Data for that (in fact, that's almost certainly overkill), but you probably do want to save it to your `Documents` folder. You can just save the JSON object to a file using `writeToFile`. Then, when it tries to retrieve the information from the server at some future date, if it's not found, look for the information in the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Yes, this technique I'm looking for. Thanks Rob :)

Answer (score 4):

> or I should use core data to store the data from JSON.

I don't even know what makes to think you'd be obliged to use CoreData if you're using JSON. It's definitely not a must. They are two distinct technologies, with a totally different purpose. For example, using JSON for quick communication to your server is just fine.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Thanks. Yes, basically there's little sense in comparing a data storage/database system with a data serialization format.